# Memory page alignment doesn't seem to affect performance...?

Tags: c++, caching, memory, memory-alignment

I am developing an application for which performance is a fundamental issue. In particular, I was willing to organize a tree-like structure that needs to be traversed really quickly in blocks of the same size as my memory page size so that it would reduce the number of cache misses needed to reach a leaf.

I am quite a novice in the art of memory optimization. As far as I understand, the process of accessing the main memory goes more or less as follows:

- CPUs have several layer of caches of increasing size and decreasing speed.
- Every time some data that I need is already in the cache, it is fetched from the cache (cache hit).
- If it is not in the cache, it will be fetched from the main memory.
- Anytime something is loaded from the main memory, the *whole* page (or pages) containing the data are loaded and stored in the cache. In this way, if I try to access locations in memory that are close to the ones I already fetched from the main memory, they will already be in my CPU cache.

However, if I organize my data in blocks of the same size as my memory page size, I thought that it would also be needed to *align* that data properly, so that whenever a new block of my data needs to be loaded only one page of memory will need to be fetched from the main memory rather than the two pages containing the first half and the second half of my data block). In principle, shouldn't a correctly aligned data block mean only one access to the memory rather than two? Shouldn't that more or less double memory performance?

I tried the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

#define BLOCKS 262144
#define TESTS 131072

unsigned long int utime()
{
    struct timeval tp;
    gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);
    return tp.tv_sec * 1000000 + tp.tv_usec;
}

unsigned long int pagesize = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
unsigned long int block_slots = pagesize / sizeof(unsigned int);
unsigned int t = 0;
unsigned int p = 0;

unsigned long int test(unsigned int * data)
{
    unsigned long int start = utime();

    for(unsigned int n=0; n<TESTS; n++)
    {
        for(unsigned int i=0; i<block_slots; i++)
            t += data[p * block_slots + i];

        p = t % BLOCKS;
    }

    unsigned long int end = utime();

    return end - start;
}

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));

    char * buffer = new char[(BLOCKS + 3) * pagesize];

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<(BLOCKS + 3) * pagesize; i++)
        buffer[i] = rand();        

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<pagesize; i++)
        cout<<test((unsigned int *) (buffer + i))<<endl;

    cout<<"("<<t<<")"<<endl;
    delete [] buffer;
}
```

This code instantiates more or less 1 GB of empty bytes, fills them with random numbers. Then the function test is called with all the possible shifts in a memory page (from a 0 shift to a 4096 shift). The test function interprets the pointer provided as a group of blocks of data and carries out some simple operation (sum) over those blocks. The order of access to the blocks is more or less random (it's determined by the partial sums) so that every time a new block is accessed it is nearly certain not to already be in the cache.

The function test is then timed. In all the shift configurations but one I should observe some timing, while in one particular shift configuration (the null shift, maybe?) I should observe some big improvement in terms of efficiency. This, however, does not happen at all: all the shift timings are perfectly compatible with each other.

Why does this happen and what does this mean? Can I just forget about memory alignment? Can I also forget about making my data blocks exactly as big as a memory page? (I was planning to use some padding in case they were smaller). Or maybe something in the cache management process is just unclear to me?

Comment: Side note: There are std C 'aligned_alloc' and 'free' (Windows: '_aligned_malloc' and '_aligned_free')

Comment: (That's nice! Will use those for sure next time!)

Comment: Try smaller page sizes too (_SC_PAGE_SIZE might be 4096)

Comment: _SC_PAGE_SIZE is indeed 4096! I will try with smaller pages.

Comment: I think I am getting it to my problem! Maybe I was confusing the notion of memory page and cache line size. The first is usually 4096 bytes but it doesn't have to do with the caching process, while the second is often not bigger than 64 bytes! Could this be the cause of my misunderstanding?

Comment: Yes, very much so.  Cache line size may affect the performance of your heavy lifting process, but spreading your data on more memory blocks will actually slow it down, possibly dramatically as you will get more page faults or even may start swapping data to the swap file.  Packing your structures may help reduce the memory footprint and improve timings.

Comment: @chqrlie Sorry, I didn't get that. What is a page fault? Is that somehow related to a cacheing mechanism as well? And why is it that I don't see any performance change with misaligned data?

Comment: A page fault occurs when memory referenced by the process is not present in actual physical memory.  In normal execution, it may occur the first time you access a piece of allocated memory.  If you and the other running processes use more memory than is physically available, the system uses *virtual memory*: it copies some memory temporarily to disk to free some space for the asking process to continue its chores. There is a large penalty when this happens.

Comment: Regarding *misaligned data*, you shoud not use this terminology to refer to  data that is not aligned on cache line boundaries or even more stringent values.  Misaligned data usually refers to mutibyte types stored at bogus addresses, such as `int` stored at adresses not multiple of `int` size.  Such misalignment may cause crashes on some systems (PowerPC for example) but may also cause no noticeable penalty on some other systems.

Comment: That is much more clear now. Thank you!

Comment: Regarding performance, fiddling with memory alignment is probably not your best bet to improve speed.  You should run a good profiler and check which functions use the most time.  Focus then on improving these functions.  You may also be using an inefficient algorithm with inadequate time complexity.  Working on that may yield *huge* improvements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77343/discussion-between-matteo-monti-and-chqrlie).